# Keyboard opens always once input get focus in ios device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, keyboard

The keyboard appears whenever a text input is first responder.In my current application, the keyboard opens when I click on the input, but whenever i click on the "go" or "return" button, it disappears. I want the keyboard to be open by default all the time until / unless the user clicks on any back event.

```js
inputchatvar.focus();
keypressed=false;
$('#inputchat').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        keypressed=true;
        onKeyPressed(e,$scope,inputchatvar,spn);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to get focus on input whenever the input box is generated dynamically?

Comment: Is this a webview served to both iOS and Android? On iOS, you could achieve this by ensuring a text input is given "first responder" when your page loads, and there is a delegate method for UITextViews called `shouldResignFirstResponder`, which you could have return false, so the keyboard never disappears. Although, you need to ensure that you don't block a different text view from being able to gain first responder, so it's not as simple as just returning false. I do not know how to achieve this functionality from a web view.

Comment: Yes it is a web View, it is working properly only in few devices such as iphone 6s plus  & few more android devices